# Rotate single imageList image

Tags: c#

Im creating a simple, snake game. Using C#
As you can see in the screenshots. The head of the snake is always looking up the screen. Basically, it doesnt rotate according to where it points. Up. Down. Left. Right.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7cOr.png)
I want to modify so that it rotates the image of the head according to direction.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DQTW.png)

I believe this is done by creating a method with an if statement inside that has some kind of rotation logic.
The movement is controlled using a switch statement.

heres the whole code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SnakeGame
{
    public partial class frmSnake : Form
    {
        Random rand;
        enum GameBoardFields
        {
            Free,
            Snake,
            Bonus
        };

        enum Directions
        {
            Up,
            Down,
            Left,
            Right
        };

        struct SnakeCoordinates
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        GameBoardFields[,] gameBoardField; //array of game board fields
        SnakeCoordinates[] snakeXY; //array of snake coordinates for body and head (head is always index [0]
        int snakeLength; //after the snake eats bonus, another piece of body is added and length is increased by 1
        Directions direction; //direction where the head is facing
        Graphics g;

        public frmSnake()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gameBoardField = new GameBoardFields[11, 11]; //playable game board size is 10x10 (index 0 to 9). The other 2 indexes are for the wall
            snakeXY = new SnakeCoordinates[100]; //index 0 to 99 (10x10 is playable game board size)
            rand = new Random();
        }

        private void frmSnake_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            picGameBoard.Image = new Bitmap(420, 420); //35 pixels * 12 fields (10 fields of game board + 2 fields for the wall)
            g = Graphics.FromImage(picGameBoard.Image);
            g.Clear(Color.GreenYellow);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                //top and bottom walls
                g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[6], i * 35, 0);//moving 35 pixels to the right
                g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[6], i * 35, 385); //moving 35 pixels to the right, but on the bottom of the game board (starting in index 1; so it's 35*11 = 385)
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
            {
                //left and right walls
                g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[6], 0, i * 35); //moving 35 pixels down
                g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[6], 385, i * 35); //moving 35 pixels down, but starting on the right side of the game board (starting from index 1; so it's 35 * 11 = 385
            }

            //initial snake body and head
            snakeXY[0].x = 5; //head
            snakeXY[0].y = 5;
            snakeXY[1].x = 5;//first body part
            snakeXY[1].y = 6;
            snakeXY[2].x = 5;//second body part
            snakeXY[2].y = 7;

            g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[5], 5 * 35, 5 * 35); //head
            g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[4], 5 * 35, 6 * 35); //first body part
            g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[4], 5 * 35, 7 * 35); //second body part

            gameBoardField[5, 5] = GameBoardFields.Snake; //head
            gameBoardField[5, 6] = GameBoardFields.Snake; //first body part
            gameBoardField[5, 7] = GameBoardFields.Snake; //second body part

            direction = Directions.Up;
            snakeLength = 3;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Bonus();
            }
        }

        private void Bonus()
        {
            int x, y;
            var imgIndex = rand.Next(0, 4);

            //if bonus is randomly generated on a snake field or another bonus field, then keep looping and generating new coordinates
            do
            {
                x = rand.Next(1, 10);
                y = rand.Next(1, 10);
            }
            while (gameBoardField[x, y] != GameBoardFields.Free);

            gameBoardField[x, y] = GameBoardFields.Bonus; //set the field to bonus
            g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[imgIndex], x * 35, y * 35); //draw the randomly generated bonus picture in the randomly generated coordinates
        }

        private void frmSnake_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Up:
                    direction = Directions.Up;
                    break;
                case Keys.Down:
                    direction = Directions.Down;
                    break;
                case Keys.Left:
                    direction = Directions.Left;
                    break;
                case Keys.Right:
                    direction = Directions.Right;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void GameOver()
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("GAME OVER");
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //delete the end of the snake
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.GreenYellow, snakeXY[snakeLength - 1].x * 35,
                snakeXY[snakeLength - 1].y * 35, 35, 35);
            //set the game board filed of the last body part to be free
            gameBoardField[snakeXY[snakeLength - 1].x, snakeXY[snakeLength - 1].y] = GameBoardFields.Free;

            //move snake field on the position of previous one
            for (int i = snakeLength; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                snakeXY[i].x = snakeXY[i - 1].x;
                snakeXY[i].y = snakeXY[i - 1].y;
            }

            g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[4], snakeXY[0].x * 35, snakeXY[0].y * 35);

            //change direction of the head
            switch (direction)
            {
                case Directions.Up:
                    snakeXY[0].y = snakeXY[0].y - 1;
                    break;
                case Directions.Down:
                    snakeXY[0].y = snakeXY[0].y + 1;
                    break;
                case Directions.Left:
                    snakeXY[0].x = snakeXY[0].x - 1;
                    break;
                case Directions.Right:
                    snakeXY[0].x = snakeXY[0].x + 1;
                    break;
            }

            //check if snake hit the wall
            if (snakeXY[0].x < 1 || snakeXY[0].x > 10 || snakeXY[0].y < 1 || snakeXY[0].y > 10)
            {
                GameOver();
                picGameBoard.Refresh();
                return;
            }

            //check if snake hit its body (if the head coordinates corespond with game board field coordinates of Snake, the snake hit its body)
            if (gameBoardField[snakeXY[0].x, snakeXY[0].y] == GameBoardFields.Snake)
            {
                GameOver();
                picGameBoard.Refresh();
                return;
            }

            //check if snake ate the bonus
            if (gameBoardField[snakeXY[0].x, snakeXY[0].y] == GameBoardFields.Bonus)
            {
                //add another body part after the last body part of the snake
                g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[4], snakeXY[snakeLength].x * 35,
                    snakeXY[snakeLength].y * 35);
                //set the field of the newly added body part to be of Snake
                gameBoardField[snakeXY[snakeLength].x, snakeXY[snakeLength].y] = GameBoardFields.Snake;
                snakeLength++;

                //we only want to generate bonus if there is still a room for it on the board.
                //we don't want to draw bonus on top of a snake. If we didn't do this if statement and are game board would be filled with
                //snake body, the Bonus() method would go into infinite loop because in that method, we loop until we find a valid Free field
                if (snakeLength < 96)
                    Bonus();

                this.Text = "Snake - score: " + snakeLength;
            }

            //draw the head
            g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[5], snakeXY[0].x * 35, snakeXY[0].y * 35);
            //change the game board field of new head to be of Snake
            gameBoardField[snakeXY[0].x, snakeXY[0].y] = GameBoardFields.Snake;

            //refresh the whole game board
            picGameBoard.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

Comment: The head should get rotated in the frmSnake_KeyDown() method.  When the new direction is in the same direction a previous piece of the snake most games do not allow snake head to move.  the code is more complicated to allow two pieces of the snake to occupy the same cell of the board.

Comment: I see your point..what about using a ".RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);" function for the snake imglist element or "e.Graphics.RotateTransform(30.0F);"? as a graphics element, cos they are of graphics type. g.DrawImage(imgList.Images[5], 5 * 35, 5 * 35);"<----this is the head g is...[5] being the imageIndex.

Comment: I was thinking, make the head its own separate graphics element..i mean, there must be a way this can be achieved. a method.

Comment: The snake is 3 pieces snakeXY.  So you just have to rotate the first piece.